# Rewrite minecraft server (getting/edit source and recompile)

Tags: java, ide, minecraft

I want to edit the minecraft server code and add/remove things, I need or not.

- First, am I allowed to edit the minecraft server code?
- And I get the
  source of the minecraft_server.jar in IntelliJ, but if I want to
  compile, I get 100 errors because in the code there are things like: 
  `switch(1.$SwitchMap$io$netty$handler$codec$http$websocketx$WebSocket08FrameDecoder$State[((State)state()).ordinal()]) {`

I really don't know what to do with these errors, because in the finshed jar, it's in there like my example.

Minecraft Server: https://minecraft.net/download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the source for minecraft servers is intended to be closed (You should not be able to even obtain it).

However, source for modded servers might be open, check Bukkit and similar projects.

Keep in mind that if you were able to find an open project, and you decided to add or delete various things, you are SOLELY responsible for ensuring that clients can still connect and operate properly.

Projects like Bukkit can be modified by writing your own plugins, so unless you want to REALLY change how minecraft operates (by adding new blocks or something!), you should be able to just write your own plugin without laying a hand on the server source code.

I admire your enthusiasm, but make sure you know what you're getting yourself into! :)

Comment: I know bukkit, and it is allowed to rewrite bukkit but i need to change some classes from minecraft server and i can't do this with plugins :)

Comment: Right! If you want to remove things or modify to add new functionality, you can do this! Do not edit the code directly from mojang. Find a project like bukkit, and grab THEIR source code. This is completely legal, and you are less likely to run into issues, as the code will be more readable instead of something that you have decompiled.

Comment: I know, but bukkit only "rewrites" some classes and the minecraft server code is added when i build the jar, and if i try to edit the minecraft_server.jar (which is added by compiling) i can't cause the error i get in main post

Comment: Strange. I would have thought Bukkit completely wrote the code on their version. If it is the case that they only change certain methods/classes, and the original jar is still included, then you can not legally modify the original jar, but have the right to modify any code that the Bukkit team wrote, or add your own code. If the Bukkit team managed to override default mojang classes, then perhaps you can study how they did it, and override even more of the original code!

Comment: I wish you luck! Editing such a large project may be daunting, but if you succeed, the reward is great! :)

Answer (score 1):

The Minecraft server is not open source. So you won't legaly get the source files.

> i want to edit the minecraft server code and add/remove things, i need or not.

I doubt there are things you don't need and if so... don't use them.

But there are OpenSource minecraft servers (like bukkit), that can easily be customized with plugins.

Comment: Yeah i know bukkit, but with plugins i can't do enough, thats why i need to change some classes and there is the main thread which runs tasks i don't need

Comment: what tasks exactly do you not need?

Comment: every, except damage ticks (like fire does)

Comment: how are you moving then?

Answer (score 1):

use BuildTools as explained in spigot, after you got all the folders
go inside the folder Spigot and go inside the folder Spigot-Server 
then inisde src then main then java then net then minecraft then server and there
is the source code, modify the stuff you want in those .java files and when you are ready go back to the folder Spigot/Spigot-Server and put this command
mvn clean package
and thats it... you may need to install some dependencies like maven ... but that will make the spigot.jar inside the folder target with the minecraft modifications...

Comment: if you want just minecraft not spigot you can get http://www.modcoderpack.com/
and uncompile the minecraft server there... and use that source on eclipse with the jars and you would run it there and even debug mode and compile it... intelig should be the same... if need help msg me xD

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Minecraft Forge (Google it) for server and client modding, if Bukkit isn't what you want.